# How to filter PrimeNG Data table column, where field is a JSON

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a Data Table with two columns, each one having a filter input. Values are populating in rows as expected. The only problem lies with "director" filter. Fields are defined as:

```
this.moviecols = [
    { field: "name", header: 'NAME' },
    { field: "directorstatus", header: 'DIRECTOR STATUS' }
]
```

Response from Server:

```
{
    director: {name: null, status: "Pro"}
    name: "Star Wars"
}
```

I am able to filter movies with "name" column:

```
<input *ngIf="col.field != 'director'" pInputText type="text" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
```

But for "director status" column, where I'm displaying the status field, following code is not working:

```
<input *ngIf="col.field == 'directorstatus'" pInputText type="text" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, col.field['status'], col.filterMatchMode)">
```

Comment: Map your json to have a flat list ? `directorName`, `directorStatus` ? I don't think you can pass a custom filter function to the turbotable..

Comment: I'm quite new to Angular. Can you please provide code snippet on how to do that?